# Why GCC can't pass options to `gas` assembler with `-Wa,-adhln=a.lst`?

Tags: gcc, gnu-assembler

When I want to generate the list file of `a.c` with the name `a.lst`, I execute the command:
    `gcc -v -S -Wa,-adhln=a.lst a.c`
and some of the output is as following:

```
gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-S' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu a.c -quiet -dumpbase a.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase a -version -o a.s -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security
```

So, according to the output, I can't find the options of assembler `-adhln=a.lst` is being passed, and there is no `a.lst` file generated. My `gcc` version is `gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413`, `as` version is `GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26`. What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Wa` option passes flags to the *assembler*.

Your command uses `-S` which means "do not run the assembler".